# Give an example of a ring in which an ideal of an ideal is not an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Obviously it's not $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: See:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144022/subideals-of-an-ideal .

Comment: There's a classic text that's sadly out of print-Rings, Modules and Linear Algebra by B. Hartley, T.O. Hawkes,that contains many wonderful examples and counterexamples in basic ring and module theory.I was trying to get it republished last year and the estate refused. I think it's a perfect reference for this question and those like it.