# A finite associative ring with non-transitive ideals?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I'm after a ring R which is finite and associative, but with non-transitive ideals.  That is, there exists some J an ideal of R, and I an ideal of J, such that I is not an ideal of R...  Plenty of examples of non-transitivity in infinite settings, but haven't found one that is finite...

Comment: Related (not duplicate): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144022/subideals-of-an-ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example is $R=\mathbb{F}_4[x]/(x^2)$, $J=(x)$, and $I=\{0,x\}$.  You can get many similar examples by taking $J$ to be any ideal in a finite ring such that $J^2=0$ and $I$ to be an additive subgroup of $J$ that is not closed under multiplication by general elements of $R$.

Comment: Thank you!  I may be missing something completely obvious so please forgive me, but it seems here that I = {0,x} cannot be an ideal of J since I is not even a subring?

Comment: The product of any two elements of $J$ is $0$, so any additive subgroup of $J$ is an ideal.

Comment: Ah yes, I do remember this result now.  However, sorry to be painfully annoying... but I can't get my head around why {0, x} is an additive 'subgroup'... it doesn't appear to be closed under addition since 2x and 3x should be included?

Comment: $2x=0$, since you're taking polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_4$ and $2=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_4$.

Comment: I thought this would mean 4x = 0, since this field has 4 elements?  Also, if that is the case, how is I different to J?  J = (x) would then only have elements 0 and x too?

Comment: The field $\mathbb{F}_4$ can be defined explicitly as $\mathbb{F}_2[y]/(y^2+y+1)$.  So $0=2$ in $\mathbb{F}_4$, and you can call its four elements $0,1,y,$ and $y+1$.  The ideal $J$ contains $yx$ and $(y+1)x$ in addition to $x$ and $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be the ring of upper triangular $3\times 3$ matrices over a finite field, i.e.
$$
R=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\0&0&g\end{pmatrix}: a,b,c,d,e,f,g\in F\right\}.
$$
Let $J$ be the ideal
$$
J=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&0&a\\0&0&b\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}: a,b\in F\right\}
$$
and let $I$ be
$$
I=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&0&a\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}: a\in F\right\}
$$

Comment: This doesn't work unless the second row first entry is made a field variable.