# Example that ideals are not transitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I need to think of an example of a ring R with ideals I and J where I is an ideal of J and J is an ideal of R, but I is not an ideal of R.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068158/a-finite-associative-ring-with-non-transitive-ideals

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144022/subideals-of-an-ideal